# Is there any way to programmatically interact with android UI elements to fill out forms in an app?

Tags: android

In a similar way that I could use javascript in a browser's developer console to write text in input fields, check radio buttons, and click buttons in a webpage, I would like to interact with an app to automatically fill out some forms (not a web form in a mobile browser, but a native app with text fields, radio buttons, and other buttons). Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. This is a basic functionality and and with a quick google/stackoverflow search you could have figured it out.

Comment: @gioravered I have [googled this](https://www.google.com/search?q=Is+there+any+way+to+programmatically+interact+with+android+UI+elements) and only came across questions/answers regarding creating and interacting with elements when developing my own app. What I'd like to do is interact with other apps

Comment: Ohh. Sorry I misunderstood. My bad :\

Answer (score 0):

There are some things you can do:

```
view.performClick();

view.performLongClick();
```

For some views:

```
view.setText("Hello world!");
```

For `CompoundButton`s like `RadioButton`:

```
view.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: That only works for your own app.

Comment: @Cactusroot I am not developing my own app. What I'd like is to be able to interact with other apps.